# Difference of two DataTables in c# using LINQ

Tags: linq, datatable

II have two data tables as follows

```
dtOne
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 101  |  ABC
 102  |  XYZ
 103  |  MNO
 104  |  PQR
--------------------------

dtTwo
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 101  |  FGH
 102  |  XYZ
 104  |  GPS
--------------------------
```

I just want the result as data which is `in dtOne` and  `not in dtTwo` (dtOne-dtTwo)

```
dtResult
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 103  |  MNO
--------------------------
```

How can i achieve this .

I have used except method of LINQ but that is giving the result like this
     101  |  ABC

```
 103  |  MNO
 104  |  PQR
 101  |  FGH

 104  |  GPS
```

Thats means matching both column in except method

Comment: What's the condition for your data selection?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find rows that meet criteria based on multiple columns in the DataTable, try something like the following

```
string stationToFind = "ABC";
DateTime dateToFind = new DateTime(2016, 5, 26);
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("station") == stationToFind 
                 && row.Field<datetime>("date") == dateToFind).ToList();
```

If you are only expecting one row, then you can use .FirstOrDefault() instead of .ToList()

Comment: I have not only ABC ,,,I have many values which are duplicate

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what criteria you are searching for.  Do you need to find all rows for a specific station?  Or a specific station and date range?

Comment: not specific station .....I have a  datatable in which 4 column  now i want to  filter latest data based on datetime and also uniqe station wise

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("station", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("max_temp", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("min_temp", typeof(double));

        dt.Rows.Add("XYZ", 14.5, 3.5);
        dt.Rows.Add("XYZ", 14.5, 3.5);
        dt.Rows.Add("XYX", 13.5, 3.5);
        dt.Rows.Add("ABC", 14.5, 5.5);
        dt.Rows.Add("ABC", 12.5, 3.5);
        dt.Rows.Add("ABC", 14.5, 5.5);

        var maxvalue = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(s => s.Field<double>("max_temp"));

        var coll = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<double>("max_temp").Equals(maxvalue)).
            Select(s => new { station = s.Field<string>("station"), maxtemp = s.Field<double>("max_temp"), mintemp = s.Field<double>("min_temp") }).Distinct();

        foreach (var item in coll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.station + " - " + item.maxtemp + " - " + item.mintemp);
        }
```